# curl not working on windows

Tags: php, curl

This is the error which I am getting on running my script:

```
[content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.015 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] =>
```

The script shown in below:

```
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$output=curl_exec($ch);

$abc=curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);                   
    //echo $output;
    print_r($abc);
```

Please help me out.............

Comment: What was the info from `curl_errno($ch)` ?

Comment: 6 is the info from curl_errno($ch)

Answer (score 0):

The info from your curl_errno() means "Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.". So your hostname is either wrong or needs to be included in your local hosts file if it's not a valid name resolvable with your current DNS server.

```
echo curl_errno($ch)
```

result:

```
CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)
```

If you need a hosts entry, it's in this file:

c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Also see:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: i am still facing this issues sometimes its throwing CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6) and some times (0)
when it is 0 its working fine when it is 6 its not working same dns ,host

Comment: Maybe your url is changing or your DNS/internet-connection is acting up?